# Flux: Trigger parent methods from children in JSX

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

Suppose you have a `Dropdown` React component:

```
var Dropdown = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="dropdown" />
    );
  },

  itemSelected: function (item) {
    this.setState({
      value: item.props.value
    });
  }
});
```

And a corresponding `Option`:

```
var Option = React.createClass({
  _onClick: function () {
    this.props.onSelect(this);
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="item" onClick={this._onClick}>{this.props.value}</div>
    );
  }
});
```

Now imagine you use these components together like so:

```
var ColorForm = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>Pick a color</label>
        <Dropdown>
          <Option onSelect={???.itemSelected} value="red" />
          <Option onSelect={???.itemSelected} value="blue" />
          <Option onSelect={???.itemSelected} value="green" />
        </Dropdown>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Notice the **`onSelect={???.itemSelected}`** bit.

How do I pass the parent dropdown's `itemSelected` method to each child?

I know that if I create a *custom* dropdown class, it's easy, but this defeats the purpose of components:

```
var ColorDropdown = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="dropdown">
        <Option onSelect={this.itemSelected} value="red" />
        <Option onSelect={this.itemSelected} value="blue" />
        <Option onSelect={this.itemSelected} value="green" />
      </div>
    );
  },

  itemSelected: function (item) {
    this.setState({
      value: item.props.value
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `onSelect` attribute to child `Option` elements inside the `Dropdown::render` method using a combination of `this.props.children`, `React.Children.map`, and `React.cloneWithProps`:

```
var React = require('react/addons');

var Option = require('./Option');

var Dropdown = React.createClass({

  itemSelected: function (item) {
    this.setState({
      value: item.value
    });
  },

  render: function () {
    var self = this;
    var children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function (child) {
      if (child.type !== Option.type) {
        return child;
      } else {
        return Reat.cloneWithProps(child, {
          onSelect: function () {
            self.itemSelected(this);
          }
        });
      }
    });

    return (
      <div className="dropdown">
        {children}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

So now you don't need to set `onSelect` for each `Item` child:

```
var ColorForm = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>Pick a color</label>
        <Dropdown>
          <Option value="red" />
          <Option value="blue" />
          <Option value="green" />
        </Dropdown>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

See the similar code for radio buttons: http://jaketrent.com/post/send-props-to-children-react/

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor -- I added example code to illustrate the combination of knowledge from that article necessary to accomplish what I needed. Cheers~